# How to create a color bar in Matrix laboratory?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I can create a false color, but I cannot color the bar in figure below.
How can I create a colorbar for the figure below?

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you have been trying, and what doesn't work? Add some code to your question, and the current state of your figure...